# Adding new security rule to Network Security group in Azure through Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-nsg

I am trying to add a custom security rule to one of my network security groups through Java SDK API. The code I am using is below ([taken from reference](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/network-java-manage-network-security-group/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/network/samples/ManageNetworkSecurityGroup.java)):

```
NetworkSecurityGroup nsg = azure.networkSecurityGroups().getById(nsgID);
        nsg.update()
                    .defineRule("Custom")
                        .allowInbound()
                        .fromAnyAddress()
                        .fromAnyPort()
                        .toAnyAddress()
                        .toPortRange(5405)
                        .withProtocol(SecurityRuleProtocol.UDP)
                        .withDescription("Allow Custom")
                        .withPriority(180)
                        .attach()
                    .apply();
        }
```

The code seems to execute fine with no errors or exceptions, but at the end of it - I am not able to see my new rule listed at all as seen from my azure console. I need some help to understand why this could be so or any pointers to debug further!

Comment: You can take a look at this [link](https://github.com/nvonstein/azure-sdk-nsg-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/network/samples/ManageNetworkSecurityGroup.java).

Comment: Hi - I am using the example from the same link you given.

Comment: OK, it seems it would be "NetworkSecurityRule.Protocol.UDP" for the protocol. And I suggest you can show the nsg id after getting it for a check.

Answer (score 0):

From looking on your code, the only thing I see that might be problematic is the call to **toPortRange** with just one parameter. Try switching to a call to **toPort**.

Take a look at **WithDestinationPort** definitions (there are 4 of them for different types) on the **[Azure SDK for Java](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/)** site.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi - Sorry, that was a copy, paste mistake from my side I believe. I was indeed using **toPortRange(5405,5407)** in my code. Based on your suggestion, I also tried the call with **toPort(5406)** but no change in the result. I am not seeing that this rule is getting added.

Comment: Try running the following command in powershell to check if you see the rule from there:
Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name  [nsg-name] -ResourceGroupName [rg-name]
    | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name [rule-name]